# Powershell 7.2 Profile can't create

Tags: powershell-core

In my pc with Windows 10 I installed Powershell 7.2.2 from Microsoft Store and now I wanna use Oh My Posh but i can't find, create or edit the $PROFILE file.

- If I type echo $PROFILE this no return nothing.
- If I type notepad $PROFILE, it open a empty notepad and i don't know where store it (file > save > path is my desktop)
- If I type New-item –type file –force $profile, a message says error "path can't be null" ($profile not exists).

Any can help me?

Comment: [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2) and [`$PROFILE` in *about_Automatic_Variables*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#profile)…

Comment: @JoseFZ Already try New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force but not work, message say "Path cannot be null" is because $PROFILE not exists, but can't create

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Share `$profile.psobject.properties|Select-Object -Property Name,Value` and/or `$profile|Get-Member -MemberType Properties`.